# Renyi divergence for continuous variable in Python

Tags: python

I have to write Python script to calculate Renyi divergence. It is simple for discrete variable, but  I'm dealing with continuous variable. I have a lot of problems because of numerical mistakes. I have successfully estimated pdf for my sample. It is how my code looks like:

```
def cont_renyi_divergence(pdf1, pdf2, alpha, minimum, maximum):
    def integrand(x):
        return ((pdf1(x))**alpha) * ((pdf2(x))**(1-alpha))
    def KL_integrand(x):
        return (pdf1(x)) * log((pdf1(x))/(pdf2(x)), e)
    if alpha == 1:
        return -integrate.quad(KL_integrand, minimum, maximum)[0]
    else:
        return (1/(1-alpha))*log(integrate.quad(integrand, minimum, maximum)[0], e)
```

where pdf1 and pdf2 are based on Gaussian distribution (mean and variance for pdf1 are 30 and 5, mean and variance for pdf2 are 30 and 10). Minimum and maximum are the smallest/biggest variable in sample 1 (pdf1) or sample 2 (pdf2). This is the definition of my function, that calculates Renyi divrgence. The problem is, that the return of this function is not equal to the [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFQmz.gif), which tells us divergence for two normal (Gaussian) distribution. I know, that this is a hard topic, but I would be happy for any answer or advice.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is equal to the equation. I put variance instead of standard deviation in formula. Beside that, it has to be alpha-1 instead of 1-alpha in cont_renyi_divergence definition.